# Downloaded sql file/db as backup, found gibberish that can't be found in wordpress pages or posts. What to do?

Tags: wordpress, malware

I made a couple of wordpress database backups before making some adjustments on a site. Found some new problems, so I checked my work to see if a new problem was something I'd done, or if it wasn't correctly handled on the original site...I did this by opening up the original backup sql file and searching for a word, and saw a whole bunch of inappropriate verbiage in the file. Stuff that has nothing to do with the content of the website. Possibly inflammatory sentences involving politics which I know the site owners would never have put there (they are a retail site).

I ran some checks to see whether or not the site had MalWare, and the software didn't see any warnings.

I checked the pages, posts, and comments on the site, and do not see anything from the sql files on the site itself. The site owners had mentioned in passing that they'd had a site break-in previously. I assumed it had been cleaned up.

- Does the stuff that I found in their sql file prove that it hasn't been cleaned up?
- What are the best steps to remove that material without breaking the site?
- And does this material being in the db negatively impacted their SEO?

Your thoughts and advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Does the stuff that I found in their sql file prove that it hasn't been cleaned up?

Not necessarily. The owners may have overwritten posts or restored previous revisions and the bad content you are seeing may actually be in post revisions - which would not be visible.

To verify this: Login to your hosting account, open phpmyadmin, select the database for this website, click the SQL tab and run this query:

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_content` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "revision"
```

If you see the bad content in the results then what you saw in the SQL file was likely from the revisions.

2) What are the best steps to remove that material without breaking the site?

There are plugins to delete old revisions. See here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/delete+revisions/  or (if you are comfortable with doing this) you can directly delete them from the database. Just make sure you backup first!

3) And does this material being in the db negatively impacted their SEO?

Old revisions should not be crawled by search engines and should have no impact on SEO.

Comment: Such a great response to my many questions. Thank you for the detailed answer!